# Python - what is the difference between random and random2 modules?

Tags: python, random, pip, sudo

when I was unable to install random module (via **sudo pip install random** command), I looked around and see that random2 is the new module (backported from Python3 into Python2?).

I am able to run **sudo pip install random2** without any problems.  My question however is - Is random2 a substitute for random and therefore the first install failure is not an issue?   Or is it?

Please let me know.   Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean install the `random` module, the `random` module comes bundled with python already doesn't it? Did you try just running `import random` in python?

Comment: `random2` is there to help you write code that works in Python 2 and Python 3. Despite its name, it's not an upgrade on `random`, which is a built in module that doesn't need installing. P.s. if you're using sudo with pip, you're probably doing something the wrong way :-)

Comment: Oops!   I meant to ask "is random2 a substitute for random...."

Answer (score 0):

The "random" module should come pre-included in both python2 and python3, especially if you're working on the more recent versions of each of these. Try just using:

```
import random
```

in your project/file and you should be able to import the module and use it just fine.